# Can you control any other parameter when using log4net?

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

In my code I have Db logging using log4net. 
I noticed that the class that does the logging has this code.

```
 public class Logger
    {
        readonly log4net.ILog _log;
        public Logger()
        {
            XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            _log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("Oracle_Log_Appender");
        }


        public void Log(string logString)
        {
                _log.Debug(logString);
        }
    }
```

The string that I pass to this mechanism gets inserted to a log table in the message column. I would like to have one more column which has ID values that will enable me to search the table for the correct message. The example I can think of is:
I am working on a series of customer objects. Each object has a primary key with an ID.
If any of them fail, I want to log it in the following fashion.

```
OBJECT_ID           MESSAGE                               OBJECT_TYPE
1001                Failed to fetch credit report         Customer
```

Can I do this using log4net?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Log4Net and extra fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795310/log4net-and-extra-fields)

Answer (score 1):

While you browse an older [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1795310/3619) (with answers!) on the same topic... this code sample is not [idiomatic](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/introduction.html#Logger%20hierarchy) log4net. `ILog` instances should be static readonly and named by the class they are in.

```
private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(<nameofclass>));
```

Manage your appenders, filters, and levels by the namespace of the classes doing the logging. Not by a single name in the logger. So, make sure your db access is all in the same namespace (or namespace root). For example

> MyProject.Infrastructure.Oracle

There's also no reason to hide the rich `ILog` interface behind this goofy wrapper class.