# Log4Net c# AdoNetAdapter Additional Fields

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I have seen multiple links on how to do this and my version is techically working.

Example: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795310/log4net-and-extra-fields)

So, I have added a new property, Unit_Name, to my code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["Unit_Name"] = "Bob " + i.ToString();
    log.Fatal("This is fatal");
}
```

And in the config file for the Console Appender

```
 <appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger  %property{unit_name} - %message %newline" />
  </layout>
 </appender>
```

This works, so moving forwards I added this to my AdoNetAdapter section.

```
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[UnitName],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger,@unit_name, @message, @exception)" />
```

and a parameter section

```
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@unit_name" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="200" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property(Unit_Name)" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
```

Now on testing all is still working, but the above parameter should be displaying the string Bob 1, Bob 2, etc. But on looking at the database table, I am getting the following:

```
{log4net:HostName=GBRCL33199, log4net:Identity=, log4net:UserName=userName, Unit_Name=Bob 0}(Unit_Name)
```

This must be a config error but I cannot see where  or what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for those that looked at this.

I knew it must have been something I did. As it happens, changing the conversionPattern string below

```
<parameter>
    <parameterName value="@unit_name" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="200" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property(Unit_Name)" />
    </layout>
</parameter>
```

to

```
<parameter>
    <parameterName value="@unit_name" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="200" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{Unit_Name}" />
    </layout>
</parameter>
```

fixed the problem. Or if you still cannot see it. I changed "%property(Unit_Name)" to "%property{Unit_Name}".